# Convert List<int[]> into an object of type ICollection<int, int[]>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, many-to-many

I have two tables in an DB First MVC3 project with a many-to-many link between the tables.

These tables combine to produce an editable matrix with a post back through an Ajax call which passes back a simple array.

Because of the many-to-many relationship I now need alter the array from this:

```
List<int[]>
```

With values like this:
{AssetId: 1, CourseId: 2}{AssetId: 1, CourseId: 3}{AssetId: 1, CourseId: 4}{AssetId: 2, CourseId: 3}{AssetId: 2, CourseId: 4}

To an:

```
ICollection<int, int[]>
```

With values like this:

{AssetId: 1, CourseId[2, 3, 4]}{AssetId: 2, CourseId[3, 4]}

I'm stuck, any help or even a point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: I know you've provided the AssetId and CourseId's for clarity, but I don't understand how {AssetId: 1, CourseId:2} fits into a List<int[]>. Do you possibly mean List<int[]> { [2,3,4], [3,4] }?

Comment: Mike, that's what I mean.  I think I've done but it still won't save as it throws some vague DBEntityUpdate exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` method to group it by an index of your array, for sample:

```
var groupedResult = list.GroupBy(x => x[0]);
```

And use a `foreach` statment to loop in the result:

```
foreach(var item in groupedResult)
{
  var assetId = item.Key ;
  foreach(int courseId in item)
  {
     // courses Id here
  }
}
```

Solution you suggest:

```
var courseIds = list.Where(o => o[0] == item[0]).Distinct();
```

Comment: I think I've done it but by using distinct.   var courseIds = Data.Where(o => o[0] == item[0]).Distinct(); and then a foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you for checking my anwser. I've posted your solution.